# Can't create multiple S3 buckets from CloudFormation yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a yaml file to create a stack with CloudFormation. However when it comes to create some S3 buckets the script fails giving me a 400 Bad Request error in the console. I tried to run a script that does only this, but has the same result. This is the yaml file i'm using

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
    ArtifactsBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: artifacts.bucket
        Description: S3 Bucket Name for CodeBuild Artifacts
    DevBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: dev.bucket
        Description: S3 Bucket Name for Dev environment.
    StagingBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: staging.bucket
        Description: S3 Bucket Name for Staging environment
    ProductionBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: production.bucket
        Description: S3 Bucket Name for Production environment

Resources:

    # S3 Bucket for build artifacts
    BuildArtifactsBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          AccessControl: Private
          BucketName: !Sub '${ArtifactsBucket}'

    # S3 Bucket for Dev environment
    DevS3Bucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          AccessControl: Private
          BucketName: !Sub '${DevBucket}'

    # S3 Bucket for Staging environment
    StagingS3Bucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          AccessControl: Private
          BucketName: !Sub '${StagingBucket}'

    # S3 Bucket for Production environment
    ProductionS3Bucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          AccessControl: Private
          BucketName: !Sub '${ProductionBucket}'
```

I really don't understand what is wrong with this, since if i left only one S3 Bucket resource it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's entirely possible that you're hitting a throttle in the S3 control api.

To avoid excessive parallel requests, you can add a `DependsOn` parameter to force the buckets to be created sequentially:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
    ArtifactsBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: artifacts.bucket
        Description: S3 Bucket Name for CodeBuild Artifacts
    DevBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: dev.bucket
        Description: S3 Bucket Name for Dev environment.
    StagingBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: staging.bucket
        Description: S3 Bucket Name for Staging environment
    ProductionBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: production.bucket
        Description: S3 Bucket Name for Production environment

Resources:

    # S3 Bucket for build artifacts
    BuildArtifactsBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          AccessControl: Private
          BucketName: !Sub '${ArtifactsBucket}'

    # S3 Bucket for Dev environment
    DevS3Bucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          AccessControl: Private
          BucketName: !Sub '${DevBucket}'
        DependsOn: "BuildArtifactsBucket"

    # S3 Bucket for Staging environment
    StagingS3Bucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          AccessControl: Private
          BucketName: !Sub '${StagingBucket}'
        DependsOn: "DevS3Bucket"

    # S3 Bucket for Production environment
    ProductionS3Bucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          AccessControl: Private
          BucketName: !Sub '${ProductionBucket}'
        DependsOn: "StagingS3Bucket"
```

Here all the buckets will be created sequentially.  You may be able to batch them into a few groups instead of strictly one-at-a-time; experiment and see what works.